# Is there any hope for this power supply to work on 220V rather than 110V?

Tags: power-supply, ac

I stupidly moved my laser printer with me overseas without checking whether it would take 220V. I assumed it would be like my desktop computer and accept both.

Anyway, here I am with a 110V printer in a 220V country. The label says 110V 50/60Hz.

I've opened the printer to look at the power supply, and I also found the service manual.

On the board, there is a 250V fuse, a 125V fuse, and a smaller fuse. According to the schematics, the AC input first goes through the 250V F1 fuse, then the 125V F2 fuse, then the smaller one (F3).

There is also a somewhat large capacitor that says 200V 270uF.

Do you think it's possible this power supply would accept 220V without modification, but it's not labeled as such for whatever reason? I think Sony did that on the PlayStation for instance to try and curb the grey market.

Here are pictures of the board, and the service manual.

[service manual (relevant pages: 165, 167, 168)](https://mega.nz/#!KAgm1CqQ!pudTZ3tGM3kzjupeseYDQHdDftGm9TpPBniDOCI6XEo)

[image: board]
[image: fuses]
[image: capacitor]
[image: schematic 1]
[image: schematic 2]

Comment: The type label says 110V, and the components are clearly only fit for 110V. No way this thing is doing more than burning down on 220V.

Comment: the fact that this printer even comes with a service manual with a schematic might indicate it's a high-quality device and it might financially make sense to buy a 110V->220V transformer. They're not that expensive.

Comment: oh, nevermind, that is a small office/consumer laser printer that's 9 years old. Go on ebay and buy a similar used model. Cheaper. If you need to make some money, sell the remainder of your toner cartridge.

Comment: The big capacitor is rated for 200V. It will explode when 220Vac is applied. If it was universal mains, the capacitor would have been rated 450V or higher.

Comment: Sadly, no. The large capacitor is the one shown at far left bottom in the diagram. It is rated at 200 VDC. Rectifying AC give VDC of ~= 1.4 x VAC so at 110 VAC you get about 15V VDC. Apply mains at double that voltage and you get VDC well above cap rating. Instant death,. **This is an indicator that the rest of the cicruit will also not tolerate 230 VAC mains**. You can buy 110:230 VAC transformers. You need an appropriate wattage rating. For interest - where have you moved from - to?

Comment: Sometimes product conversions are easy if they have a 110/220V transformer, then all you have to do is switch the Line input on primary side to its appropriate voltage, This is not one of those times.

Comment: Found a MPW3053 board on ebay with the picture - sent from Germany and only 13.5€.  Get one and replace your board.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: NO.

> There is also a somewhat large capacitor that says 200V 270uF.

The capacitor is for 200V, which is sufficient for a fully rectified ~120V. 
~230-240 would burn it with its 340DC. ~230-240V tend to use 400V capacitors.

I don't quite understand the triac part and it does requires AC to function. I suppose it's a heating element and in such a case, you cannot use 240V w/o a transformer.
Otherwise, not recommended but if it's a low powered switch power supply, you can cut half of the wave of 230-240V via a single diode and feed DC to the full wave rectifier. Again not recommended and relatively dangerous.